# Shiny Flexdashboard Object Not Found

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, flexdashboard

I am working on making a graph of data in a flexdashboard with runtime shiny.

Here is where I bring my data in and manipulate it for downline use:

````
---
title: "Provider Dashboard"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(tibbletime)
library(scales)

source("S:\\clean_names.R")
source("S:\\optimal_bin_size.R")

df_los <- readr::read_csv(
  "G:\\los.csv"
  ) %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  filter(ward_cd != "EMER") %>%
  filter(med_staff_dept != "?") %>%
  filter(med_staff_dept != "Pathology")

df_los$dsch_date <- lubridate::mdy(df_los$dsch_date)
df_los <- as_tbl_time(df_los, index = dsch_date)

df_ra <- readr::read_csv(
  "G:\\ra.csv"
) %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  filter(ward_cd != "EMER") %>%
  filter(med_staff_dept != "?") %>%
  filter(med_staff_dept != "Pathology")

df_ra <- rename(df_ra, pt_id = "pt_no_num")
df_ra$dsch_date <- lubridate::mdy(df_ra$dsch_date)
df_ra$adm_date  <- lubridate::mdy(df_ra$adm_date)
df_ra <- as_tbl_time(df_ra, index = dsch_date)

df_a <- df_los %>%
  dplyr::select(
    pt_id
    , dsch_date
    , los
    , performance
    , z_minus_score
    , lihn_service_line
    , hosim
    , severity_of_illness
    , pyr_group2
    , med_staff_dept
    , ward_cd
  )
df_b <- df_ra %>%
  dplyr::select(
    pt_id
    , readmit_count
    , readmit_rate_bench
    , z_minus_score
  )
df_los_ra <- dplyr::inner_join(df_a, df_b, by = "pt_id") %>%
  as_tbl_time(index = dsch_date)
````

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
gmc_los_ra <- reactive(
  {
    df_los_ra %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_svc_line == "All" | lihn_service_line == input$losra_svc_line
        ) %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_hosp_pvt == "All" | hosim == input$losra_hosp_pvt
      ) %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_soi == "All" | severity_of_illness == input$losra_soi
      ) %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_pyr_cat == "All" | pyr_group2 == input$losra_pyr_cat
      ) %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_med_staff == "All" | med_staff_dept == input$losra_med_staff
      ) %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_dsch_ward == "All" | ward_cd == input$losra_dsch_ward
      ) %>%
      collapse_by("monthly") %>%
      dplyr::group_by(dsch_date, add = T) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(
        excess_ra = round(mean(readmit_count - readmit_rate_bench), 2)
        , excess_los = round(mean(los - performance), 2)
      )

  }
)

renderPlot({

  print(gmc_los_ra())

  gmc_los_ra() %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(
        x = excess_los
        , y = excess_ra
      )
    ) +
    scale_x_continuous(
      expand = c(0,0)
      # If I uncomment this, an error of Object Not Found excess_los occurs
      # , limits = c(
      #   min(excess_los)
      #   , max(excess_los)
      # )
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous(
      expand = c(0,0)
      # , limits = c(
      #   min(excess_ra)
      #   , max(excess_ra)
      # )
     ) +
    ylab("Excess Readmit Rate") +
    xlab("Excess LOS") 
    # labs(
    #   title = "Gartner Magic Quadrant - Excess LOS vs Excess Readmit Rate"
    #   , subtitle = "Red Dot Indicates Zero Variance"
    #   ) +
    # theme(
    #   legend.position = "none"
    #   , axis.title.x = element_text(
    #     hjust = 0
    #     , vjust = 4
    #     , colour = "darkgrey"
    #     , size = 10
    #     , face = "bold"
    #     )
    #   , axis.title.y = element_text(
    #     hjust = 0
    #     , vjust = 0
    #     , color = "darkgrey"
    #     , size = 10
    #     , face = "bold"
    #     )
    #   , axis.ticks = element_blank()
    #   , panel.border = element_rect(
    #     colour = "lightgrey"
    #     , fill = NA
    #     , size = 4
    #     )
    #   ) +
    # annotate(
    #   "rect"
    #   , xmin = 0
    #   , xmax = max(excess_los)
    #   , ymin = 0
    #   , ymax = max(excess_ra)
    #   , fill = "#F8F9F9"
    #   ) +
    # annotate(
    #   "rect"
    #   , xmin = 0
    #   , xmax = min(excess_los)
    #   , ymin = 0
    #   , ymax = min(excess_ra)
    #   , fill = "#F8F9F9"
    #   ) +
    # annotate(
    #   "rect"
    #   , xmin = 0
    #   , xmax = min(excess_los)
    #   , ymin = 0
    #   , ymax = max(excess_ra)
    #   , fill = "white"
    #   ) +
    # annotate(
    #   "rect"
    #   , xmin = 0
    #   , xmax = max(excess_los)
    #   , ymin = 0
    #   , ymax = min(excess_ra)
    #   , fill = "white"
    #   ) +
    # geom_hline(
    #   yintercept = 0
    #   , color = "lightgrey"
    #   , size = 1.5
    #   ) +
    # geom_vline(
    #   xintercept = 0
    #   , color = "lightgrey"
    #   , size = 1.5
    #   ) +
    # geom_label(
    #   aes(
    #     x = 0.75 * min(excess_los)
    #     , y = 0.90 * max(excess_ra)
    #     , label = "High RA"
    #     )
    #   , label.padding = unit(2, "mm")
    #   , fill = "lightgrey"
    #   , color="black"
    #   ) +
    # geom_label(
    #   aes(
    #     x = 0.75 * max(excess_los)
    #     , y = 0.90 * max(excess_ra)
    #     , label = "High RA/LOS"
    #     )
    #   , label.padding = unit(2, "mm")
    #   , fill = "lightgrey"
    #   , color = "black"
    #   ) +
    # geom_label(
    #   aes(
    #     x = 0.75 * min(excess_los)
    #     , y = 0.90 * min(excess_ra)
    #     , label = "Leader"
    #     )
    #   , label.padding = unit(2, "mm")
    #   , fill = "lightgrey"
    #   , color = "black"
    #   ) +
    # geom_label(
    #   aes(
    #     x = 0.75 * max(excess_los)
    #     , y = 0.9 * min(excess_ra)
    #     , label = "High LOS"
    #     )
    #   , label.padding = unit(2, "mm")
    #   , fill = "lightgrey"
    #   , color = "black"
    #   ) +
    # geom_point(
    #   color = "#2896BA"
    #   , size = 2
    #   ) +
    # # where you want to be
    # geom_point(
    #   data = data.frame(x = 0, y = 0)
    #   , aes(color = 'red')
    #   , size = 3
    #   )

})
```

As soon as I uncomment the `limits` portion of the `scale_x_continuous()` command I get the error of `Object Not Found: excess_los` even though it is clearly defined above and works in the initial `ggplot()` portion of the code. Am I missing something here? If I change it to `limits = NA` then it seems to work fine. I know they should produce the same results but my question is why does my code not work as is especially since I call min/max() on excess_los and excess_ra later on in the plot all of which fail with the same error.

The R Markdown console does get output from the filter portion of the code:

```
# A time tibble: 17 x 3
# Index: dsch_date
   dsch_date  excess_ra excess_los
   <date>         <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 2018-01-31     -0.01      0.1  
 2 2018-02-28      0.02     -0.21 
 3 2018-03-31      0        -0.54 
 4 2018-04-30      0.03     -0.34 
 5 2018-05-31      0.01     -0.22 
 6 2018-06-30     -0.03     -0.31 
 7 2018-07-31      0        -0.8  
 8 2018-08-31      0.02     -0.32 
 9 2018-09-30     -0.01     -0.08 
10 2018-10-31     -0.01     -0.11 
11 2018-11-30     -0.01     -0.32 
12 2018-12-31     -0.01     -0.290
13 2019-01-31      0        -0.14 
14 2019-02-28      0        -0.290
15 2019-03-31      0.01     -0.06 
16 2019-04-30     -0.01     -0.33 
17 2019-05-31     -0.03     -0.580
Warning: Error in continuous_scale: object 'excess_los' not found
  171: continuous_scale
  170: scale_x_continuous
  169: renderPlot [<text>#37]
  167: func
  127: drawPlot
  113: <reactive:plotObj>
   97: drawReactive
   84: origRenderFunc
   83: output$outab893253c4e6ccbd
    3: <Anonymous>
    1: rmarkdown::run
```

I tried to do something like `gmc_los_ra$excess_los` but get an error of `Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to the following:

```
gmc_los_ra <- reactive(
  {
    df_los_ra %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_svc_line == "All" | lihn_service_line == input$losra_svc_line
        ) %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_hosp_pvt == "All" | hosim == input$losra_hosp_pvt
      ) %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_soi == "All" | severity_of_illness == input$losra_soi
      ) %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_pyr_cat == "All" | pyr_group2 == input$losra_pyr_cat
      ) %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_med_staff == "All" | med_staff_dept == input$losra_med_staff
      ) %>%
      filter(
        input$losra_dsch_ward == "All" | ward_cd == input$losra_dsch_ward
      ) %>%
      collapse_by("monthly") %>%
      dplyr::group_by(dsch_date, add = T) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(
        excess_ra = round(mean(readmit_count - readmit_rate_bench), 3) * 10
        , excess_los = round(mean(los - performance), 2)
      ) %>%
      as.data.frame()

  }
)

x_min <- reactive({min(gmc_los_ra()$excess_los)})
x_max <- reactive({max(gmc_los_ra()$excess_los)})
y_min <- reactive({min(gmc_los_ra()$excess_ra)})
y_max <- reactive({max(gmc_los_ra()$excess_ra)})

renderPlot({

  print(gmc_los_ra())

  gmc_los_ra() %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(
        x = excess_los
        , y = excess_ra
      )
    ) +
    scale_x_continuous(
      expand = c(0,0)
      , limits = c(
        x_min()
        , x_max()
      )
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous(
      expand = c(0,0)
      , limits = c(
        y_min()
        , y_max()
      )
     ) +
    ylab("Excess Readmit Rate") +
    xlab("Excess LOS") +
    labs(
      title = "Gartner Magic Quadrant - Excess LOS vs Excess Readmit Rate"
      , subtitle = "Red Dot Indicates Zero Variance"
      ) +
    theme(
      legend.position = "none"
      , axis.title.x = element_text(
        hjust = 0
        , vjust = 4
        , colour = "black"
        , size = 10
        , face = "bold"
        )
      , axis.title.y = element_text(
        hjust = 0
        , vjust = 0
        , color = "black"
        , size = 10
        , face = "bold"
        )
      , axis.ticks = element_blank()
      , panel.border = element_rect(
        colour = "lightgrey"
        , fill = NA
        , size = 4
        )
      ) +
    annotate(
      "rect"
      , xmin = 0
      , xmax = x_max()
      , ymin = 0
      , ymax = y_max()
      , fill = "#F8F9F9"
      ) +
    annotate(
      "rect"
      , xmin = 0
      , xmax = x_min()
      , ymin = 0
      , ymax = y_min()
      , fill = "#F8F9F9"
      ) +
    annotate(
      "rect"
      , xmin = 0
      , xmax = x_min()
      , ymin = 0
      , ymax = y_max()
      , fill = "white"
      ) +
    annotate(
      "rect"
      , xmin = 0
      , xmax = x_max()
      , ymin = 0
      , ymax = y_min()
      , fill = "white"
      ) +
    geom_hline(
      yintercept = 0
      , color = "lightgrey"
      , size = 1.5
      ) +
    geom_vline(
      xintercept = 0
      , color = "lightgrey"
      , size = 1.5
      ) +
    geom_label(
      aes(
        x = 0.75 * x_min()
        , y = 0.90 * y_max()
        , label = "High RA"
        )
      , label.padding = unit(2, "mm")
      , fill = "lightgrey"
      , color="black"
      ) +
    geom_label(
      aes(
        x = 0.75 * x_max()
        , y = 0.90 * y_max()
        , label = "High RA/LOS"
        )
      , label.padding = unit(2, "mm")
      , fill = "lightgrey"
      , color = "black"
      ) +
    geom_label(
      aes(
        x = 0.75 * x_min()
        , y = 0.90 * y_min()
        , label = "Leader"
        )
      , label.padding = unit(2, "mm")
      , fill = "lightgrey"
      , color = "black"
      ) +
    geom_label(
      aes(
        x = 0.75 * x_max()
        , y = 0.9 * y_min()
        , label = "High LOS"
        )
      , label.padding = unit(2, "mm")
      , fill = "lightgrey"
      , color = "black"
      ) +
    geom_point(
      color = "#2896BA"
      , size = 3
      ) +
    #  #where you want to be
    geom_point(
      data = data.frame(x = 0, y = 0)
      , mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = 'red')
      , size = 3
      )

})
```

The addition of the following did the trick:

```
x_min <- reactive({min(gmc_los_ra()$excess_los)})
x_max <- reactive({max(gmc_los_ra()$excess_los)})
y_min <- reactive({min(gmc_los_ra()$excess_ra)})
y_max <- reactive({max(gmc_los_ra()$excess_ra)})
```